# Ionic 2 non-interactive authentication

Tags: android, ios, authentication, ionic2

I'm building a mobile app for iOS and Android using ionic 2. I want the users' accounts to be device based so the users do not need to manually register or authenticate. How is this usually achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why dont you use this plugin and get the device info 
[Ionic Native Device](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device/)

So you can access these information

- Device uuid
- Manufacturer
- Serial

And then create a unique ID by combining or with any Algo
Example :

```
import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device';

loginid:any;
constructor(private device: Device) {

    this.loginid = device.uuid+device.serial;


 }
```

Use this LoginId to Auth the user Automatically.  Hope this helps.
Thanks :)

Comment: If the app and the backend communicate over https, are there any security concerns I should be aware of?

Comment: Take a look at JWT tokens , https://www.joshmorony.com/using-json-web-tokens-jwt-for-custom-authentication-in-ionic-2-part-2/

Comment: Looks like JWT where the shared secret is the device ids is the way to go. Thanks!